# Can not apply js effect on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

I want to apply the simple javascript rainydrop effect, http://maroslaw.github.io/rainyday.js/demo2.html

But it doesn't work. I got very unexpected result as the following picture.

I think the problem is the asset pipeline ? But I have no ideas

[image]

### Here's the layout joseph_memo.html.haml

```
!!!
%html{lang: "en"}
  %head
    %meta{charset: "utf-8"}/
    %title rainyday.js demo #4
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true    
    %style{media: "screen"}
      :cdata
        img { display: none; }
        body { overflow: hidden; }
        \#canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
    %script{src:  asset_path("rainyday/dist/rainyday.0.1.1.min.js"), type: "text/javascript"}
    :javascript
      function run() {
        var engine = new RainyDay('canvas', 'background', window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
          engine.gravity = engine.GRAVITY_NON_LINEAR;
          engine.trail = engine.TRAIL_DROPS;
          engine.VARIABLE_GRAVITY_ANGLE = Math.PI / 8;
          engine.rain([
            engine.preset(0, 2, 0.5),
            engine.preset(4, 4, 1)
          ], 50);
      }

  %body{onload: "run();"}
    %img#background{alt: "background", src: asset_path("rainyday/img/city.jpg")}/
    #cholder
      %canvas#canvas
```

Comment: you should create a jsfiddle, so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

**Layout**

The problem is likely due to you including the javascript directly in your `application` layout.

You're using an [anonymous function](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/beware-anonymous-functions/) (notorious for not working correctly on Rails), and then binding to the body's `on-load` event. You'll be *much* better using [unobtrusive] javascript[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) & putting the code into your `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//require rainyday/dist/rainyday.0.1.1.min.js

var make_it_rain = function() {
    var engine = new RainyDay('canvas', 'background', window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    engine.gravity = engine.GRAVITY_NON_LINEAR;
    engine.trail = engine.TRAIL_DROPS;
    engine.VARIABLE_GRAVITY_ANGLE = Math.PI / 8;
    engine.rain([
        engine.preset(0, 2, 0.5),
        engine.preset(4, 4, 1)
    ], 50);
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", make_it_rain);
```

This should get things working, *if* your `rain` plugin is working correctly. I would go into more detail about how to better structure your application, but that would be better for another answer I think